# Is it possible to use two DatePickers in inline mode in one component in Vaadin 14?

Tags: java, components, vaadin, custom-component, vaadin14

Is there a way to create two DatePickers in Vaadin 14 in one component? I mean something like this: [image]

but without the time. This is a component created in Vaadin 8 with two InlineDateFields but in Vaadin 14 there is no InlineDateFields(is there any replacement for this field from Vaadin 8?).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does Vaadin not have dialogs?

Comment: @DevilsHnd it have but this is a popup which it comes from textfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no replacement for the `InlineDateField` component in Vaadin 14 or later.

The closest is the `<vaadin-month-calendar>` web component ([source](https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/blob/master/packages/date-picker/src/vaadin-month-calendar.js)), which is an internal part of the new DatePicker component. You might be able to hack something together with that, if you first create a Java component on top of it. Note, that it hasn't been designed/implemented to be used standalone, so it might not work very nicely.

In the directory on the other hand exists [Date Range Picker add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/date-range-picker) for picking date range.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the addon it's very helpful, but there are some problems with it which must be discussed but here is not the topic. Thank you very much :)